# Grouping Content-Types Menu Bolt CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

I got some project using Bolt CMS, i am relatively new to this CMS related project, so please spare me if my question is irrelevant or seems stupid.

So, this project has many data need to be inputed from backoffice, something like this

```
Group Menu A
- SubMenu 1
  * Create
  * Read
  * Update
  * Delete
- SubMenu 2
  * Create
  * Read
  * Update 
  * Delete
Group Menu B
- SubMenu 1
...
```

Using Bolt CMS, these submenus can be defined as `ContentTypes` and this task is relatively easy by editing `contenttypes.yml`. But at Bolt's backoffice these `ContentTypes` appear as separate menu, something like this

```
Content Type 1
* View
* Add
Content Type 2
* View
* Add
...
```

So, my question, is it possible to group Content Types with other Content Types in Bolt CMS?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question, is it possible to group Content Types with other Content Types in Bolt CMS?

Short answer is no.

Slightly longer answer, is that hierarchical ContentTypes are being worked on, have been successfully prototyped, and will probably land in 2.4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and info. But, for now is there any work around while waiting for next release? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Well one thought it how you order the ContentTypes in `app/config/contenttypes.yml` is the order they appear in the the backend menu.